# How to get dpi in picture within Android environment

Tags: java, android, jar, draw, dpi

Need: picture’s px to inch or mm in android.

Extend:
(1) How dose PhotoShop(Windows) can get picture’s dpi with precise?
(2) Do android has a reasonable picture DPI parsing library?

My research:
First Android platform shielded the.AWT.Image library, so you can use the Commons-Imaging (or Sanselan) third party library, but some of these third party libraries, it does not resolve all the pictures’ DPI.
I analyze the image of the 16 binary code, and found in the JPEG that DPI does not this necessary attribute, if the fourteenth byte is 00, said no DPI attribute value.There are such cases in BMP. So the third party library can not resolve all the pictures of the DPI.

Comment: Images don't really have a dpi.  They have a width and a height.  They may have been designed for a given size, but when you draw one all that matters is pixels-  width and height.  If you want to draw it to some other size, you have to do that yourself by drawing the scaled bitmap

Comment: Thanks!
I want to draw with a map image, so I need that make images have there own real size.（Map image has there own scale, such as 1:1000 but is used M or CM not PX）
Dpi is a way to make image has there real size which can convert real position to map image.
I know images don't really have a dpi, I just want to convert between real size to virtual size.